# XML pagination with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, pagination, simplexml

Below is code I'm using to parse XML file, however file has many records and I want to paginate it, and display 20 records per page.

I also want the pagination links at bottom of page so users can go to other pages as well. It should be something like, if no value is give then it will start from 0 to 20 else if value is 2 start from 40 and stop at 60, `test.php?page=2`.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('xmlfile.xml', 0, true);

foreach ($xml->product as $key => $value) {
    echo "<a href=\"http://www.example.org/test/test1.php?sku={$value->sku}\">$value->name</a>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
    $startPage = $_GET['page'];
    $perPage = 10;
    $currentRecord = 0;
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('xmlfile.xml', 0, true);

      foreach($xml->product as $key => $value)
        {
         $currentRecord += 1;
         if($currentRecord > ($startPage * $perPage) && $currentRecord < ($startPage * $perPage + $perPage)){

        echo "<a href=\"http://www.example.org/test/test1.php?sku={$value->sku}\">$value->name</a>";    

        //echo $value->name;

        echo "<br>";

        }
        }
//and the pagination:
        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($currentRecord / $perPage); $i++) {
           echo("<a href='thispage.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>");
        } ?>
```

Comment: Exactly the same thing worked, Thank you so much. @Phil

Comment: @Phil very sad that you did the homework for him and didn't let him learn applying the pagination concept by himself.

Comment: @stefreak thanks for your intention, I've to learn it one way or another, Everybody's way of learning is different, so is mine, I learn quick by seeing working examples, or you can say some people are educated others are well trained, I don't feel bad saying that I'm the one leans toward well trained. Thanks

Comment: PHP has a [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/LimitIterator) for a reason. The logic in the answer with `$currentRecord` is broken, you might be looking for [`SimpleXMLElement::count()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.count) instead to get the total number of records.

Answer (score 2):

As `SimpleXMLElement` is a `Traversable`, you can do the pagination with a [`LimitItertor`](http://php.net/LimitIterator) which ships with PHP.

To get the total number of product elements you can use the `SimpleXMLElement::count()` function.

Pagination works like outlined in the hundreds of other questions, I preferable use the [`LimitPagination` type](https://gist.github.com/hakre/4469154) for it.

It takes the current page, the total amount of elements and elements per page as arguments (see as well: [PHP 5.2 and Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14184729/367456)). It also has a helper function to provide the `LimitIterator`.

Example:

```
$products = $xml->product;

// pagination
$pagination = new LimitPagination($_GET['page'], $products->count(), 20);

foreach ($pagination->getLimitIterator($products) as $product) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to output a pager that allows to navigate between the pages, the `LimitPagination` has more to offer to make that a bit easier, e.g. for just all pages highlighting the current page (here exemplary with brackets):

```
foreach ($pagination->getPageRange() as $page)
{
    if ($page === $pagination->getPage()) {
        // current page
        printf("[p%d] ", $page); 
    } else {
        printf("p%d ", $page);
    }
}

foreach ($pagination->getPageRange() as $page)
{
    if ($page === $pagination->getPage()) {
        // current page
        printf("[p%d] ", $page); 
    } else {
        printf("p%d ", $page);
    }
}
```

Interactive online demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OjvNcO
Less interactive online demo: http://eval.in/14176

Answer (score 1):

You could use php's `array_slice` function (Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Start would be `$page * $itemsPerPage`, end would be `$page * $itemsPerPage + $itemsPerPage` and the number of pages would be `ceil(count($xml->product) / $itemsPerPage)`.

Example:

```
$allItems = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
$itemsPerPage = 5;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 0;

foreach (array_slice($allItems, $page * $itemsPerPage, $page * $itemsPerPage + $itemsPerPage) as $item) {
    echo "item $item";
}
```

It even works :) see: http://codepad.org/JiOiWcD1

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm don't think it was your intention but you've confused me than ever. @stefreak

Comment: No problem, I added an example and hope this helps you understand what I mean. If you are still confused, please explain what exactly confuses you.

Comment: +1 for providing at least some explanation.